# Interpolation on irregular grids

Tags: julia, interpolation, linear-interpolation

Is it possible to perform 2D interpolation in Julia where one of the coordinates is irregular? Take the following example, where `x` is irregular, but `y` is regular:

```
x = [0.5 2 3 4.;
     0.6 1 3 4.;
     0.7 2 3 5.;
     0.8 2 3 4.;]

y = [1;
     2;
     3;
     4;]

z = [1. 2. 1. 2.;
     1. 2. 1. 2.;
     1. 2. 3. 2.;
     1. 2. 2. 2.;]
```

I have tried the following with the [Dierckx](https://github.com/kbarbary/Dierckx.jl)-package, but it results in an error:

```
Spline2D(x, y, z)
```

Similarly, it seems like the [Interpolations](https://juliamath.github.io/Interpolations.jl/stable/)-package doesn't handle irregular grids yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (install `Surrogates` package if necessary):

```
using Surrogates

x = [0.5 2 3 4.;
     0.6 1 3 4.;
     0.7 2 3 5.;
     0.8 2 3 4.;]

y = [1;
     2;
     3;
     4;]
z = [1. 2. 1. 2.;
     1. 2. 1. 2.;
     1. 2. 3. 2.;
     1. 2. 2. 2.;]

points = collect(zip(repeat(1.0*y; outer=4), vec(x)));
vals = vec(z);

ks = Kriging(points, vals, [0.0, 0.0], [-5.0, 5.0]);
```

Now `ks` is an interpolation object which can accessed by calling it with a point argument e.g. `ks((xcoord, ycoord))`.

For example:

```
julia> using UnicodePlots

julia> contourplot(0.0:0.1:5.0, 0.0:0.1:5.0, (x,y)->ks((x,y));
         colorbar=false, canvas=DotCanvas)
     ┌────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
   5 │        :           ........    :.      │ 
     │       :'         :''       '.   :     .│ 
     │. ...''           :          ':  :    :'│ 
     │'''      ......   :.          :  :   :  │ 
     │       .'      :.  :.         :  :   '. │ 
     │      :         '.  '.        :  '.   ':│ 
     │     :.          :   ':..   .:    :.    │ 
     │      ':...     .:      '''''      ':   │ 
     │           ''''''                    '':│ 
     │                                        │ 
     │                                        │ 
     │                          ..............│ 
     │.           .........'''''              │ 
     │ '''''''''''' ....                      │ 
   0 │    ...'''''''    '''''''''....'''''''''│ 
     └────────────────────────────────────────┘ 
      0                                      5
```

This method uses Kriging which is an interpolation method. More information available in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging).